# Hibernate Criteria: subquery with IN

Tags: java, hibernate, db2, nhibernate-criteria

First question here:
I am using DB2 and Java Hibernate criteria.
I need a way to use a subquery in my where clause and be able to use `IN` in the subquery. But I cannot seem to find the solution.
This is what I have now:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("{alias}.arnrmb in (select arnrvb from faarvb where mgnrvb in ?)", getWarehouses().toArray(), typeArray));
```

I get this error:

```
2015-03-16 14:07:13,566 [ERROR] (SqlExceptionHelper:147) - Descriptor index not valid.
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it like this for now:

```
if (CSCommonStatics.isNotEmpty(getWarehouses())) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        ArrayList<String> warehousesList = new ArrayList<String>(getWarehouses());

        for (int i = 0; i < warehousesList.size(); i++) {
            if (i != warehousesList.size() - 1) {
                sb.append("'" + warehousesList.get(i) + "'" + ", ");
            } else {
                sb.append("'" + warehousesList.get(i) + "'");
            }
        }
        String warehousesQuery = sb.toString();

        criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("{alias}.arnrmb in (select arnrvb from faarvb where mgnrvb in (" + warehousesQuery + "))"));
    }
```

I'm still curious for a cleaner way to do this though!